# IIS 10 - IP Address And Domain Restrictions is denying all traffic

Tags: windows, security, iis, website, ipv4

I have a server that has multiple sites set up on it in IIS 10.

On one of the sites, I want to allow access to a range of IP Addresses, and deny traffic to the site from all other IP Addresses.

In IIS, in the IP Address and Domain Restrictions settings, I have added an ALLOW rule for the range of IP addresses, and a DENY rule for denying all other traffic.  However, all traffic to the site is being denied.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

[image: IIS IP Address and Restriction Settings]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At `Edit Feature Settings...` you can set the option `Access to unspecified clients:` to `Deny` and remove the lower entry.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what I was doing wrong.

The IP range I was using was my network's public IP range, but I was testing out the rules on a server that's internal on our network, and so when I instead used the internal network IP addresses, the Allow rules started working.